# Using sed to filter out students in a list

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, sed

I have a list of students, which I have saved to a text file `students.txt`.

```
John Doe Marketing Junior B
Betty Metty Engineering Junior A
James Names Nursing Sophomore B
Bob Nob History Freshman B
Hope Nope Engineering C
```

It's probably very simple, but as I am a total beginner at shell scripting, what sed pattern command prints out the people, **first and last names only**, who have an A in their major (letter @ end)?

If you could link a helpful website for sed patternsearch rules related to lists that would be great as well.

Using vim, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not the most appropriate tool for this, better use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) like this :

```
 awk '$5=="A"{print $1, $2}' file
```

### Output

```
Betty Metty
```

#### Edit, filter engineering :

```
awk '$5=="A" && $3=="Engineering"{print $1, $2}' file
```

Comment: Done using awk.

Comment: This does seem easier to use awk, yes. Thank you!

Comment: One last question: What if there need to be multiple restrictions, like they must have a B and be in engineering? Would the "&&" operator be used?

Comment: @KevinMoy, that is easy as well to do with awk.. for ex: `awk '/Engineering/ && /B$/{print $1, $2}'` ... see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/topics for more examples

Comment: Well, there's a kind of an error. If you tried to get the names of engineering students with a C, those scripts would fail as Hope Nope's record only has 4 fields. If the data is as intended, a quick fix for that is to replace `$5` with `$NF`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
John Doe Marketing Junior B
Betty Metty Engineering Junior A
James Names Nursing Sophomore B
Bob Nob History Freshman B
Hope Nope Engineering C

$ sed -nE '/A$/ s/^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/p' ip.txt 
Betty Metty
```

- `-n` don't print lines by default
- `-E` use extended regex
- `/A$/` match `A` at end of line
- `s/^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/p` capture first two non-space character sequence separated by space, leaving out rest of line and print this modified line

With GNU `sed`, for inplace editing:

```
sed -i -nE '/A$/ s/^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/p' ip.txt
```

With `vim`

```
:v/A$/d | s/\v^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/
```

- `v/A$/d` delete all lines not ending with `A`
- `|` to add another command
- `s/\v^(\S+\s+\S+).*/\1/` uses very magic mode `\v` to reduce `\` needed, much like `-E` option

Answer (score 0):

Using sed to find the matches and awk to print just the fields you want:

```
sed -n -e '/A$/p' input_file | awk '{print $1 $2}'
```

sed -n means by default don't print anything. `/A$/p` means print anything where the last character is an 'A'.

Comment: why not just `awk '/A$/{print $1" "$2}'`?

Comment: @Sundeep OP asked for sed so I started with sed, but then I realised they just wanted 2 fields which starts to get hard with sed. So yes, you are probably right, awk solution is better.